How to find the value of $\int_{1}^{2}P(x)dx$?
$1)$ If $P(x)$ is a polynomial satisfying the given conditions $P(1)=3$ and $P(2)=5$. Find the value of $$\int_{1}^{2}P(x)dx$$ ?
Now in general we define $P(x)=ax+b$.
Therefore $a+b=3$ and $2a+b=5$
Therefore $a=2$ and $b=1$. Therefore we can say that $P(x)=2x+1$. Now we can integrate out $$\int_{1}^{2}(2x+1)dx$$
Now, I asked this question to my private tutor and he said that this is the correct process.
But I really don't know that why this is the only correct process ? For the sake of convenience we can also assume
$P(x)=(ae^{x}+b)$ or $P(x)=(a\ln(x)+b)$, etc...
Then $$\int_{1}^{2}P(x)dx$$ will fetch another value.
Now which one is correct ?
Why my teacher said that $P(x)=ax+b$ is the correct answer ? I am really unable to understand.
Why $P(x)=ae^{x}+b$ or $P(x)=a\ln(x)+b$ are incorrect?

$P(x)=ae^{x}+b$ and $P(x)=a\ln(x)+b$ are not polynomials. But you are right that there are more polynomials with $P(1)=3$ and $P(2) = 5$ . Unless it is given that the polynomial is linear (degree one) the integral can not be determined from this data alone.

There is not enough information to solve this puzzle. The functions you suggest ($ae^x+b$ and $a\ln(x)+b$) are not polynomials. However, $x^2-x+3$ is a polynomial, satisfies all the requirements, and has an integral of $\frac{23}6$ instead of $4$. It's possible the question had other information you missed, or perhaps it was simply written wrong.

Presumably there were more conditions on the polynomial, like least degree or such.  As it stands, we could add any polynomial which vanished at $1$ and $2$, like $(x-1)(x-2)x^{100}$,  to $2x+1$ and these don't have to integrate to $0$.

@whatamidoing. What is the link for ?

@ClaudeLeibovici that was for the OP to have reference for algebraic and transcendental functions

@whatamidoing. $P(x)=ae^{x}+b$ and $P(x)=a\ln(x)+b$ do not generate transcendental equations. Cheers :-)

Suppose that you have $P\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=k$.
The quadratic going through the three points is
$$P(x)=a x^2+bx+c$$ with
$$a=-4 (k-4) \qquad \qquad b=2 (6 k-23)\qquad \qquad c=33-8 k$$
$$\int_{1}^{2}P(x)\,dx=\frac{2 (k+2)}{3}$$
If you choose $k=\frac {3+5}2=4$ you have  $4$ as a result. For any other value, you get whatever you want.
